# Simplify and Sqrt, inconsistent behavior?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have encountered some problems when using `Simplify` with expressions containing a square root and isolated a following test case

```
Simplify[x - #[y], x == #[y]] & /@ {Sin, Sqrt, #^s &, #^(3/2) &}
```

with a result

```
{0, x - Sqrt[y], 0, x - y^(3/2)}
```

1. Why is `x-Sqrt[y]` not simplified to `0` as in the case of `x-Sin[y]`?
2. What is the logic behind simplifying `x-y^s` to `0`, but keeping x-y^(3/2)?
3. Why do all the above differences vanish when we replace `-` with `==`? In such case

   ```
   Simplify[x == #[y], x == #[y]] & /@ {Sin, Sqrt, #^s &, #^(3/2) &}
   ```

   results in

   ```
   {True, True, True, True}
   ```

Comment: FWIW, `Sqrt[y]`'s `FullForm`  is really `Power[y, Rational[1/2]]`, just as `y^(3/2)`'s `Fullform` is `Power[y, Rational[3/2]]`, so it seems likely that the same cause (fractional powers?) is leading to the observed output in the two cases.

Comment: Furthermore: `Simplify[x - y^(3/2) == 0, x == y^(3/2)] ==> True` but `Simplify[PossibleZeroQ[x - y^(3/2)], x == y^(3/2)] ==> False`.

Comment: BTW, was it confirmed by WRI or TechSupport that this is a bug? Until it is approved, I remove the tag [tag:bugs], please only use it if there is an authentic comment from WRI or reasonable community-backing that a behaviour is indeed a bug.

Comment: I have not reported this behavior via official channels yet.  @Aky You are of course right with the `FullForm` of `Sqrt`, it is no different than the case `x == y^(3/2)`.  But still, why `x == y^s` behaves in a different way?